# How to convert a data frame into a symmetric matrix in R?

Tags: r

Here is an example:

```
 df<-data.frame(x=c(1,1,2),y=c(2,3,3),z=c(0.1,0.2,0.3))
 df
  x y   z
1 1 2 0.1
2 1 3 0.2
3 2 3 0.3
```

How to I convert it to a symmetric matrix such like:

```
    1   2   3
1 1.0 0.1 0.2
2 0.1 1.0 0.3
3 0.2 0.3 1.0
```

Where the filled values are df$z for possible df$x and df$y pairs. The diagonals have been filled as unit 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a `matrix` with all `1`s, then fill `upper.tri` and `lower.tri` according to the `order`ed rows of `df`. This also works for columns `1:2` in `"character"` format if they can be ordered adequately.

```
M <- matrix(1, nrow(df), ncol(df))
M[lower.tri(M)] <- M[upper.tri(M)] <- df[order(df$x, df$y), ][[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  1.0  0.1  0.2
# [2,]  0.1  1.0  0.3
# [3,]  0.2  0.3  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a diagonal matrix `m` and then set the offdiagonals as shown:

```
m <- diag(3)
m[cbind(df$x, df$y)] <- m[cbind(df$y, df$x)] <- df$z
m
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.1  0.2
[2,]  0.1  1.0  0.3
[3,]  0.2  0.3  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, what if the x and y are characters?

Comment: `df2 <- data.frame(x=c("x", "x", "y"),y=c("y", "y", "z"),z=c(0.1,0.2,0.3));
m2 <- diag(3);
colnames(m2) <- rownames(m2) <- names(df2);
m2[cbind(df$x, df$y)] <- m2[cbind(df$y, df$x)] <- df$z`